Inconsistent Results with SEATS and X-11 Decomposition Models in R using fpp3
I’m experiencing inconsistent behavior when applying time series decomposition models in R using the fpp3 package and would like some guidance.
I have a time series of Broad National Consumer Price Index (IPCA) (Var. % monthly) from the Brazilian Central Bank that I’ve successfully converted into a tsibble object. When I apply the X-11 decomposition model, it works perfectly, but I run into issues with the SEATS model.
library(rbcb)
library(fpp3)

ipc_pre = get_series(433, start_date='2007-02-01', end_date='2017-01-01')
ipca <- ts(ipc_pre$`433`, start=c(2007,02), freq=12)
# Transformed the ts object into a tsibble for use with fpp3
ipca_tsibble <- as_tsibble(ipca)

# Applied the X-11 decomposition model without any issues:
ipca_x11_dcmp <- ipca_tsibble |>
  model(x11 = X_13ARIMA_SEATS(value ~ x11())) |>
  components()

autoplot(ipca_x11_dcmp) +
  labs(title = "IPCA decomposition using X-11.")

# Encountered an error when applying the SEATS model:
ipca_seats_dcmp <- ipca_tsibble |>
  model(seats = X_13ARIMA_SEATS(value ~ seats())) |>
  components()

The error message was:
Model used in SEATS is different: (0 2 2)
Error in `transmute()`:
ℹ In argument: `cmp = map(.fit, components)`.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `seasonal = dcmp[, "adjustfac"]`.
Caused by error in `dcmp[, "adjustfac"]`:
! índice fora de limites
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

On a second attempt, the SEATS model executed without the components() function, but I’m unsure why the first attempt failed.
I’m puzzled as to why the X-11 model worked seamlessly while the SEATS model did not. Could there be an issue with the components() function, or is there something else at play? I would greatly appreciate any insights or explanations for the different outcomes between these two models.
UPDATE
I have performed some analysis that may be helpful.
library(seasonal)
checkX13()

(ajuste <- seas(ipca))
Model used in SEATS is different: (0 2 2)

Call:
seas(x = ipca)

Coefficients:
         Constant  AR-Nonseasonal-01  AR-Nonseasonal-02  MA-Nonseasonal-01     MA-Seasonal-12  
           0.4899             0.2852             0.1895            -0.4120            -0.2848  

and
summary(ajuste)

Call:
seas(x = ipca)

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
Constant           0.48993    0.05807   8.437  < 2e-16 ***
AR-Nonseasonal-01  0.28515    0.85572   0.333  0.73896    
AR-Nonseasonal-02  0.18951    0.57508   0.330  0.74176    
MA-Nonseasonal-01 -0.41203    0.83793  -0.492  0.62292    
MA-Seasonal-12    -0.28481    0.09321  -3.056  0.00225 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

SEATS adj.  ARIMA: (2 0 1)(0 0 1)  Obs.: 120  Transform: none
AICc: -42.99, BIC: -27.01  QS (no seasonality in final):5.008 .
Box-Ljung (no autocorr.): 25.29   Shapiro (normality): 0.9849  
Messages generated by X-13:
Warnings:
- Automatic transformation selection cannot be done on a series with zero or negative values.
- Visually significant seasonal and trading day peaks have been found in one or more of the estimated spectra.

Notes:
- Model used for SEATS decomposition is different from the model estimated in the regARIMA modeling module of
  X-13ARIMA-SEATS.

Attempted to plot the SEATS model adjustment
plot(ajuste)


qs(ajuste)
                  qs   p-val
qsori        5.00792 0.08176
qsorievadj   5.00792 0.08176
qsrsd        0.00000 1.00000
qssadj       5.00792 0.08176
qssadjevadj  5.00792 0.08176
qsirr        1.57514 0.45495
qsirrevadj   1.57514 0.45495
qssori       4.76131 0.09249
qssorievadj  4.76131 0.09249
qssrsd       0.02985 0.98519
qsssadj      4.76131 0.09249
qsssadjevadj 4.76131 0.09249
qssirr       1.60777 0.44759
qssirrevadj  1.60777 0.44759

Finally
# Error encountered with monthplot
monthplot(ajuste, col.base = 1, lty.base = 2, labels = month.abb, lwd.base = 2)
Error in monthplot.seas(ajuste, col.base = 1, lty.base = 2, labels = month.abb,  : 
  model has no seasonal component

Despite the significant seasonal MA component in the SEATS model summary, the monthplot function suggests there is no seasonal component. This contradiction is puzzling and I’m seeking insights into why this might be happening.
